# JQuery - CheckBox List

Tags: jquery

Does anyone know if there is a CheckBox List for a Drop Down List in JQuery? This seems like it could be valuable. However, I do not see one anywhere. At the same time, I would be surprised if the vibrant JQuery community hasn't created one.

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From a quick google search

[dropdown-check-list](http://code.google.com/p/dropdown-check-list/)

and the [Demo page](http://dropdown-check-list.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/dropdownchecklist.html)

Comment: Thanks! It must have been a fluke, but the page was down about an hour ago.